# Caliburn.Micro Maximize Silverlight Window

Tags: silverlight, caliburn.micro

Is there a way to Maximize the window in an out of browser Caliburn.Micro Silverlight app from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
App.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

But you can only do this if the user clicks on on a button or in elevated trust mode. Bummer